# Makefile - Deleting subdirectories of a directory

Tags: makefile

I am a complete Makefile newb, So I'm wondering how I would loop through a specific directory and remove specific subdirectories?

Say I have:

```
[app]
  |
  | - [src]
  |      |
  |      |- [foo]
  |      |
  |      |- [foo-bar]
  |      |
  |      |- [bar]
  |      |
  |      |- [baz]
  |
```

How would I loop through `src` and :

- remove foo
- remove foo-bar
- leave bar
- remove baz

I have actually about 8 specific folders I wish to delete from `src`.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why are you doing this in a make context? How would you do this if you were just writing a command or shell script to do it?

Comment: I'm just trying to 'automate' a small but tedious manual process. My thinking was that by having make handle it - non developers could essentially perform this task with minimal exp. I was thinking shell or make.

Comment: If you have a single simple command that you can write out in its entirety and doesn't need to be run routinely (based on other updated files, etc.) then make really isn't the best tool (though it can certainly be used for this) a shell script will work just as easily.

Comment: It is actually one small part of my overall Makefile - I agree that it would be overkill to use Make for this one command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clean:
rm -f /src/foo
rm -f /src/foo-bar
rm -f /src/baz
```

Comment: Still, you might just as well put this into a shell script.